# Dimensions of pdf generated by Export[...]

Tags: export, grid-layouts

I'm trying to export a `Grid` table to pdf. When I display the table in the notebook, it has a very long aspect ratio, which I want to preserve in the pdf. However, when I export using `Export["table.pdf",table]`, the result has square dimensions, and *Mathematica* has word wrapped some of the table elements. Adding the option `ImageSize->{x,y}` seems to have no effect.

Below is the desired output (what I see in the notebook):
[image: Notebook output]

Below is the output that *Mathematica* produces on export:
[image: PDF output]

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `LineBreakWithin->False` to fix this:

```
Style[Grid[ConstantArray["blah blah blah", {5, 20}], Dividers -> All], LineBreakWithin -> False]
Export["test.pdf", %]
```

[image: table output]

Answer (score 0):

If you have few of these, you can try "Save Selection As" as see in the following picture:

[image]

Comment: Not quite the solution I was after, but it is sufficient for my issue, as I do only have a handful of these tables.