# Prevent Export from wrapping Row of plots

Tags: graphics, export

I assign a few `LinePlot`s to `plotA`, `plotB`, `plotC` and present them in a `Row`, using

```
a = Row @ {plotA, plotB,plotC}
```

though with some tweaks to their appearance and alignment;

```
a = Row @ {
  Show[plotA, ImageSize -> 350], 
  Show[plotB, ImagePadding -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, {Automatic, 1}}],
  plotC
}
```

This renders beautifully in the front-end:

[image]

I now wish to export this arrangement as a single .pdf file.
Sadly,

```
Export["a.pdf", a]
```

produces a pdf which has wrapped the images:

[image]

I've tried

```
SetOptions[$FrontEndSession, PrintingStyleEnvironment -> "Working"]
Export["a.pdf", a, ImageFormattingWidth -> \[Infinity]]
```

but this does not change the wrapping.

One work-around is to turn off the line numbers ("In[n]"), via

```
SetOptions[$FrontEnd, ShowCellLabel -> False];
```

then select my row in the front-end, and use `File > Save Selection As...`

but this is a bit annoying, and I'm looking for an entirely programmatic method so I can automate this without goofing up my notebook.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the answer to [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/118365/36508), you can wrap the plots in a [`Cell`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Cell.html) and specify the [`PageWidth`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PageWidth.html) there:

```
SetOptions[$FrontEndSession, PrintingStyleEnvironment -> "Working"]

ImportString[
 ExportString[
  Cell[
   BoxData@
    ToBoxes@Row@
      Table[ListPlot[RandomReal[{0, 1}, {5, 3}], ImageSize -> 300], 3],
   PageWidth -> Infinity
   ],
  "PDF"
  ],
 "PDF"
 ]
```

[image]

The [`ImportString`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImportString.html)/[`ExportString`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ExportString.html) combo is just so you can quickly verify the result within Mathematica. To actually create a PDF file, use [`Export`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Export.html) instead of `ExportString`:

```
 Export[
  "a.pdf",
  Cell[
   BoxData@
    ToBoxes@Row@
      Table[ListPlot[RandomReal[{0, 1}, {5, 3}], ImageSize -> 300], 3],
   PageWidth -> Infinity
   ],
  "PDF"
  ]
```

Comment: Ahh certainly the `PageWidth` was respected, but this introduced some other problems (I've updated my question with the output)

Comment: @AntiEarth Did you check how the exported PDF looks like in an external viewer? There's a known issue with Mathematica and clipped regions in PDFs (see e.g. [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/94757/why-is-an-imported-plot-different-from-the-saved-one))

Comment: I couldn't write this string to a file successfully; using `WriteString` gives me a blank pdf (of the correct one-row dimensions though, I notice) and `Export` gave me an invalid file. Is there something wrong with `WriteString["test.pdf", ExportString[ ..., "PDF"]]`?

Comment: @AntiEarth Sorry, I should have specified that in the post itself - simply replace `ExportString[...,"PDF"]` with `Export["file.pdf",...,"PDF"]` to actually export the plots (see also the updated answer)

Comment: Fantastic, you've done it :) Thanks very much!

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `LineBreakWithin -> False`, as in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/80759/8253):

```
ImportString@ExportString[
    Style[Row[Table[Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}, ImageSize->300], 3]], LineBreakWithin -> False],
"PDF"
]
```

[image]